# Create webapp with full stored procedures

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api, database-first

I want to create a web application, all actions (Create, Update, Delete) should be done using SQL stored procedure. Every action in the web just calls a stored procedure and receives json data to render the view.

So what is the best framework that I can use? Please help

Comment: Procedural code like **stored procedures** is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So what is the best .Net framework that I can use?

Every .Net Framework has ways to retrieve data from database. So, it doesn't really matter what version of .NET Framework you use.

I believe you would like to know what kind of library you should use for Store Procedures. If so, you might want to look at [Dapper ORM](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper).

Dapper ORM is created by Stack Exchange, and used in a lot of sites including Stack Overflow.

It basically is a wrapper around *ADO.NET* to map SQL result to strongly type object. If you have to do the mapping manually, it is very tedious and error prone process. So, I highly recommend using Dapper ORM if you have to call Store Procedures.